# Removing unwanted characters from username field using infopath

Tags: infopath

Can anyone tell me how to remove unwanted characters from username field. 
ex:  `i:0#.w|abcventures\sreekiran.k`  I need to remove the characters which are generated before `abcventures\sreekiran.k`.

I have used `translate()` to eliminate those characters, but, it is removing `i` & `w` characters also, from the username.

Answer (score 2):

To expand on the current answers, I think they meant to use substring-after().  This will do the trick:

substring-after(userName(), "i:0#.w|")

Comment: you could've commented on an already existing answer or the question itself since this does not seem like an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use `substring-before` to remove those characters.

Answer (score 0):

To expand on Mekalikot's answer -

```
substring-before(userName(), "i:0#.w|")
```

Will return just the string after the "i:0#.w|" from the user name function. If the user name function does not include that string, however, the formula will return nothing. Since you'll get a different value from the user name function in preview vs. the browser, you'll probably need to test this with the published form.